# How to read multiple values into variable one by one in Python

Tags: python

I have list containing multiple elements, like this:

```
my_list = ['element1', 'element2', 'elementX']
```

I need to use each list element value as a variable. I think what I should do, is to call list with each element, where x is 0, 1, 2 etc.

```
variable = my_list[x]
```

I can get list length with len(my_list), but how can I then read each list element into variable, so when I later use this variable I get something like this:

```
print variable 

element 1
element 2
element X
```

Or maybe it is totally wrong way to do this?

Comment: http://scribu.net/blog/python-equivalents-to-phps-foreach.html

Comment: The only logical solution is to loop over your list.

Comment: Based on the output you say you want from `print variable`, you should do `variable = '\n'.join(my_list)`. But I don't see how that example output relates to what you say in the rest of the question so I'm probably missing the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the elements in the list:

```
for variable in list:
   do something with variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Its what that `join()` function is for , you can join your elements with '\n' but note that the list elements must be string :

```
>>> variable='\n'.join(my_list)
>>> print variable
element1
element2
elementX
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to print each item in your list on a seperate line I'd do the following:

```
variable = ["element1", "element2", "elementX"]

for item in variable:
    print item
```

Which should get you the following:

```
element1
element2
elementX
```

I prefer this over the use of `join()` as it is more readable but also because each element in the variable can continue to exist neatly on it's own, rather than squishing it into one long string like `join()` would do. The `join()` method also needs your elements in the list to be strings, but if we use a for loop our items in the list can be anything permitted (such as numbers) without having to convert them to a string where possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['element1', 'element2', 'elementX']
def do_something(var):
    """doing something with variable"""
    print(var)

#iterating
for element in my_list:
    do_something(element)
```

After running this code, you'll get:
element1
element2
element3